# How to interpret dendrogram height for clustering by correlation

Tags: r, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

Given the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(26, 28, 19, 27, 23, 31, 22, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                 x2 = c(5, 5, 7, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                 x3 = c(8, 6, 5, 7, 5, 9, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
                 x4 = c(8, 5, 3, 8, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 x5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 x6 = c(2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 37, 49, 39, 28, 30))
```

Such that

```
> df
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
1  26  5  8  8  1  2
2  28  5  6  5  1  3
3  19  7  5  3  1  1
4  27  5  7  8  1  0
5  23  7  5  1  1  1
6  31  4  9  3  0  1
7  22  2  5  4  1  3
8   1  0  1  0  0 37
9   2  0  0  0  0 49
10  1  0  1  1  0 39
11  1  0  0  0  0 28
12  1  1  1  0  0 30
```

I would like to group these 12 individuals using hierarchical clusters, and using the correlation as the distance measure. So this is what I did:

```
clus <- hcluster(df, method = 'corr')
```

And this is the plot of `clus`:

[image: dendogram]

This `df` is actually one of 69 cases I'm doing cluster analysis on. To come up with a cutoff point, I have looked at several dendograms and played around with the `h` parameter in `cutree` until I was satisfied with a result that made sense for most cases. That number was `k = .5`. So this is the grouping we've ended up with afterwards:

```
> data.frame(df, cluster = cutree(clus, h = .5))
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 cluster
1  26  5  8  8  1  2       1
2  28  5  6  5  1  3       1
3  19  7  5  3  1  1       1
4  27  5  7  8  1  0       1
5  23  7  5  1  1  1       1
6  31  4  9  3  0  1       1
7  22  2  5  4  1  3       1
8   1  0  1  0  0 37       2
9   2  0  0  0  0 49       2
10  1  0  1  1  0 39       2
11  1  0  0  0  0 28       2
12  1  1  1  0  0 30       2
```

However, I am having trouble interpreting the .5 cutoff in this case. I've taken a look around the Internet, including the help pages `?hcluster`, `?hclust` and `?cutree`, but with no success. The farthest I've become to understanding the process is by doing this:

First, I take a look at how the merging was made:

```
> clus$merge
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   -9  -11
 [2,]   -8  -10
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]  -12    3
 [5,]   -1   -4
 [6,]   -3   -5
 [7,]   -2   -7
 [8,]   -6    7
 [9,]    5    8
[10,]    6    9
[11,]    4   10
```

Which means everything started by joining observations 9 and 11, then observations 8 and 10, then steps 1 and 2 (i.e., joining 9, 11, 8 and 10), etc. Reading about the `merge` value of `hcluster` helps understand the matrix above.

Now I take a look at each step's height:

```
> clus$height
[1] 1.284794e-05 3.423587e-04 7.856873e-04 1.107160e-03 3.186764e-03 6.463286e-03 
6.746793e-03 1.539053e-02 3.060367e-02 6.125852e-02 1.381041e+00
> clus$height > .5
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Which means that clustering stopped only in the final step, when the height finally goes above .5 (as the Dendogram had already pointed, BTW).

Now, here is my question: **how do I interpret the heights?** Is it the "remainder of the correlation coefficient" (please don't have a heart attack)? I can reproduce the height of the first step (joining of observations 9 and 11) like so:

```
> 1 - cor(as.numeric(df[9, ]), as.numeric(df[11, ]))
[1] 1.284794e-05
```

And also for the following step, that joins observations 8 and 10:

```
> 1 - cor(as.numeric(df[8, ]), as.numeric(df[10, ]))
[1] 0.0003423587
```

But the next step involves joining those 4 observations, and I don't know:

1. The correct way of calculating this step's height
2. What each of those heights actually means.

Comment: You may be able to get some information from my answer here: [Determining similar users from hierarchical clustering](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91025/7290).

Answer (score 8):

Recall that in hierarchical clustering, you must define a distance metric between clusters. For example, in hierarchical average linkage clustering (probably the most popular option), the distance between clusters is define as the average distance between all inter-cluster pairs. The distance between pairs must also be defined and could be, for example, euclidean distance (or correlation distance in your case). So the distance between clusters is a way of generalizing the distance between pairs.

In the dendrogram, the y-axis is simply the value of this distance metric between clusters. For example, if you see two clusters merged at a height $x$, it means that the distance between those clusters was $x$.

Comment: Intriguing. How would I then calculate the correlation distance between clusters {9, 11} and {8, 10}, in my case?

Comment: If you are using average-linkage, then that would be $0.25(d(9,8)+d(9,10)+d(11,8)+d(11,10))$, where $d(a,b)$ is the distance (correlation distance) between instances $a$ and $b$.